# Only Data owner can retrieve his data - smart contract

Tags: solidity

i have made a smart contract where someone can store data against your public address my question is how i can restrict that only address owner can able to retrieve his data below i have attached my retrieve my function

```
    function getRecords()
    public
    view
    returns (Record[] memory)
{
    return AddressToRecord[msg.sender];
}
```

Q2: is this possible that someone cannot enter data against our address without our permission?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to ensure that only the data owner can read this data ? if so it's impossible, that data will be publicly available as contract storage can be read freely by anyone.

Comment: yeah i want to ensure that only data owner can read his data.

Comment: You can make your function allow data retrieval for the data owner only (as you already did) , but there are ways to read that data anyway. Privacy is not really a thing yet in blockchain.